# Nuxt fetch() for Firestore returns empty array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, hook

I'm using the fetch() hook [in Nuxt with Firestore](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) and when called on the server it always returns an empty array. If called from the client, it returns a populated array

```
created(){
  this.$fetch() //called on client, logs populated array and json
},
async fetch(){
  const products = await this.$fire.firestore.collection('products').get();
  const ps = products.docs.map(doc=>doc.data());
  console.log(ps); //logs an empty array on Nuxt SSR

  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/38`)
  const l = await res.json();
  console.log(l); //always logs a value on client or SSR

}
```

Can I have some guidance as to what's happening here and how it solve it? I find it odd that the call to `jsonplaceholder` always returns data, but the call to firebase does not. See below for an image of `console`

[image: image of console]

When CTRL + SHIFT + R is pressed:

[image: network tab filtered by XHR]

When there's a hot reload or client side navigation:

[image: network tab with hot reload or client side navigation]

`products.vue`

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" cols="3">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            {{ product.category }}
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: '',
    }
  },

  async fetch() {
    const products = await this.$fire.firestore.collection('products').get()
    this.products = products.docs.map((doc) => {
      return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id, ref: doc.ref }
    })

    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/38`)
    const l = await res.json()
  },
  // fetchOnServer: false
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using asyncData?

Comment: @Dharmaraj `asyncData` is blocking the render, not the actual call. Both run on server + client too. Also, both API are called client-side here. Testing server side would be: having SSR and disabling JS to see the shipped HTML to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `created()` here? You could probably remove it.

You may need `await products.docs.map(doc=>doc.data())` too?

You can always remove it with `fetchOnServer: false` as seen here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/#options

Also, you could try running the firebase code in a node.js only file and see if it's the server or not.

Comment: I use created just as an automatic way to call `$fetch` again. As if I had a button on the template that when clicked would call `$fetch`. If $fire was a client side only plugin, wouldn't it error out?

Comment: Hm, this is working `client + server` side as shown here: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/usage#fire So that let's the configuration possibility, maybe you missed something here: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/firestore? Did you checked the network tab? You do have `ssr: true` right?

Comment: I don't think ssr:true applies to firestore, only auth. In any event I don't have it and adding it in didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Actually yeah, not sure why but SSR is pretty out of discussion here at all. Since we don't really do anything on server side but rather just in the `fetch()` hook. What about the other solutions, questions that are above (answer + comments)? Especially the network tab.

Comment: asyncData yields the same result. What exactly am I looking for in the network tab?

Comment: The async request, to firestore. If it's here, is the result empty too? Is the configuration properly done upfront?

Comment: Filter it by `XHR` to only have the AJAX calls.

Comment: Not sure where is your firestore call but we will need it. I can't even see the JSONplaceholder call. Do you have some strange setup/middleware? Try to isolate this into a new page and call it there. `fetch()` should be working great.

Comment: I've added the code to the question, this is in a page (not a component) called `Products.vue` . I don't have any middleware setup. I've also added the network tab with client side navigation

Comment: I've edited it to make it more readable. Idk man, try to find what are the queries that you are sending and why they are not here. Could always make a fresh new nuxt app and try to call JSONplaceholder in the `index.vue`. Then firestore the same way of here. Too hard to get the issue in your current configuration here. It's pretty much a 1:1 session required here.

Comment: I appreciate the assist! If I figure it out I'll post back here

Comment: Also don't bother looking at the network when it HMR, it's just websocketting the new code, nothing relevant here.

Comment: I'm using the emulators and my production db is completely empty atm. I think the server calls are pulling from production and client is pulling from the emulators that's why the client side calls return populated arrays